# Running a loop while a function is true in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have a function which returns either `True` or `False`. I'm trying to perform a loop where that function is called several times until it returns `False`, and count how many times it ran.

```
import random as rand

def test_function():
   return rand.random > 0.5

count = 0 

while test_function():
   count += 1

print count
```

All this is doing is running it once though, and holding whatever value it got.

Comment: Short version of your program: `python -c "from random import randint as r; print r(0,1)"` or even `print "mean count: 0.5"` :-)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't actually my code, it was just easier to follow than what I'm really doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function with `()`.

```
return rand.random() > 0.5
```

Comment: Oh jeez. I had that part right in the code I copied this from, but this helped me realize the problem I was having was in a different part of the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to actually call `rand.random`.  Add `()` after it to do this:

```
return rand.random() > 0.5
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import random as rand
>>> rand.random
<built-in method random of Random object at 0x01DC02A8>
>>> rand.random()
0.4878133430124779
>>>
```

Right now, your code is testing if the function object itself is greater than `0.5`.

Comment: Actually, it appears it evaluates to `True`: `>>> import random;
>>> random.random > 0.5;
True`